# Best practices and implementation for macro and class-level accessor methods?

Tags: ruby, macros, metaprogramming, class-design, accessor

I'm designing/building a system of classes that all derive from a single base class.

The goal is to have easy-to-use inherited macro methods that look something like this:

```
class Something < A::Base
  full_name 'Something that goes bump in the night.'
end
```

Any code should be able to ask the class for this information (or, likely, normalized/derived infomation) later on via class-level accessor method(s).

```
puts Something.full_name
  # => "Some kind of calculated value that may or may not go bump in the night."
```

Given that `A::Base` includes/extends/somehow-otherwise-mixes-in both a module with the macro method that works something like this:

```
module MacroMethods
  private
  def full_name(full_name)
    # non-trivial, one-time-only set-up code exists here in actual usage
  end
end
```

and a module with the class-level accessor method that works something like this:

```
module AccessorMethods
  public
  def full_name
    # a non-trivial, runtime-calculated value is returned here in actual usage
  end
end
```

no matter how I mix them in, I'm continually running into naming conflicts (i.e. ‘*wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)*’) between the two.

***Note:*** *`full_name` is the simplest example of what is needed; other, more-complex macros/accessors ensure the non-flexible constraints of macro methods needing to be declared inside the class and needing to be set once-and-only-once.*

---

My question is two-fold:

1. **Is there a way to make this all work inside of the `A::Base` class?**
2. **Is this the right way to do this in Ruby?** Is there a better way go about it, achieving the same result?

Options that have been considered:

- **Calling either the macro or accessor method(s) something else.**
  *(e.g. in Something class: `set_up_full_name 'Something that …'`)*
  Downside is that the naming is confusing and unconventional.
- **Making the accessor method(s) instance-level instead of class-level.**
  *(e.g. `puts a_something.full_name'`)*
  Downside is that the traits set up by the macros are inherent to the class, not to each instance *(in some cases, only a reference to the class may be available, not an instance)*.
- **Creating a single method that handles both macro and accessor functionality.**
  *(e.g. in A::Base class: `def self.full_name(*args) …`)*
  Downside is that the macro methods can no longer be private and the RDoc looks like sh*t.
- **Using abstact/virtual-ish methods instead.**
  *(e.g. in Something class: `def self.full_name; 'Something that …'; end`)*
  Downside is that this is more code in sub-classes and is more of a Objective-C *(or C++, or Java, …)* thing than a good Ruby paradigm.

Comment: @Refactor and @Jimmy: I removed the bits of code that were specific to the simple `full_name` in order to clarify that the question isn't about simply setting and getting a static value, it's about the best paradigms in Ruby, given the need for a one-time-only macro method and a class-level accessor, regardless of value(s).

Hopefully this helps clear things up. ;-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slipp, I read your question carefully. There is no way you can have 2 different methods called `full_name` defined on the same object at the same time. BUT, you could do something like this:

```
module MacroMethods
  private
  def full_name(full_name)
    # non-trivial, one-time-only set-up code exists here in actual usage
    # this method can only be called once in the definition of any given class,
    #   because after the first call, it will be redefined!
    extend AccessorMethods
  end
end

module AccessorMethods
  public
  def full_name
    # a non-trivial, runtime-calculated value is returned here in actual usage
  end
end

class Base
  extend MacroMethods
end

class Something < Base
  full_name 'after this call, I will get a new full_name method!'
end

class SomethingElse < Base
  full_name 'so will I!'
end
```

Comment: Close… but the solution provided only allows instance-level access, i.e. `Something.new.full_name` and `SomethingElse.new.full_name`.

Comment: With a little `self.singleton_class.instance_eval` magic, I got it to work (and have editing your solution, albiet redundant). I can't believe I didn't think of this earlier. Thank you; you win.

Comment: Added puts calls at the end as well.

Comment: Glad it was helpful! Note that the original solution used `extend` on `Base`, not `include`. And when `full_name` was called on `Base`, it also used `extend`. This will create class methods... I tried it in irb.

Comment: Alex D: The question does ask for class methods. You original solution  throws `NoMethodError: private method 'full_name' called for Something:Class` when `Something.full_name` is called.

Comment: I just ran the original solution on Ruby 1.9.2p290, and `Something.full_name` returns `nil`.

Comment: Ah, I see now what you mean by the original solution (r1, not r2)… you changed it before I got a chance to see it. I'm curious why— it worked.

Comment: I also have no idea what I was thinking when I edited the code. I just rolled it back to the original.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have class macros available to certain classes, then a common base class is not the Ruby solution. Instead, you create a module that extends the base classes with the functionality you want them to have:

```
module Extensions
  def self.included(base_class)
    base_class.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    attr_accessor :full_name
  end
end

class Something
  include Extensions

  self.full_name = "Something that goes bump in the night"
end

puts Something.full_name    # => Something that goes bump in the night
thing = Something.new
puts thing.full_name        # Error
```

This overrides a hook method in `Extensions` called `Module#included` that passes any class that includes the module as an argument. The new method then calls `Object#extend` on the base class to put the methods available in `ClassMethods` *directly onto that class as class methods*. This works the same way as defining class methods, but this runs dynamically. This frees you of needing to use your only base class on a class that provides macros. Note that the methods are not defined on instances of classes that include the module.

Comment: This is essentially what I'm already doing; you can check out actual code I'm using [here](https://github.com/slippyd/red_diamond/blob/master/lib/red_diamond/model/full_name_trait.rb), if interested.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, though. I'm not seeing how this solves the problem of a class-level accessor method's name conflicting with the class-level macro method's name. From your example, it looks like there is no accessor method (calling `Something.full_name` raises an ArgumentError).

Comment: I've clarified the question by adding more example code. Hopefully this helps clear up what I'm looking for.

Comment: I updated my answer. You may need to do some research on Ruby metaprogramming before you fully understand the solution if you don't know about it already, but this should work.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer, but it still doesn't address my question at all (please see the “Note: full_name is the simplest example of what is needed…” that I added to the question).

Comment: Also, your code does not work. `Something.full_name` returns nil, and therefore `puts Something.full_name` prints a blank line.

Comment: Okay; you just need to add `self.full_name = ...`. This works now.

Comment: Am I still not explaining the problem at hand clearly? Sure it works, but it doesn't answer the question. Please let me know what part of the question you're confused with and I will try to make it clearer.

Comment: My interpretation so far has been that you want to include class macros in certain classes by a mechanism appropriate in Ruby.

Comment: Well yes, that's a very small part of it. [Programming Ruby 1.9](http://pragprog.com/titles/ruby3/programming-ruby-1-9) of the [PragProg](http://pragprog.com/) label covers that topic quite succulently in chapter 24.

Comment: So, what is your problem? What part of it am I not covering?

Comment: Pretty much all of it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like most of the other answers have the right idea, but are lacking the getter method for `#full_name`. This example might be what you're looking for:

```
class Thing
  class << self
    attr_writer :full_name

    def full_name
      "My full name is #{@full_name}"
    end
  end
end
```

With this you can do something like this:

```
> Thing.full_name = 'Thing Class'
=> "Thing Class"
> Thing.full_name
=> "My full name is Thing Class"
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems needlessly complex. Why not just use an attribute on the parent class?

```
class Base
  class << self
    attr_accessor :full_name
  end
end

class A < Base; end

class B < Base; end

A.full_name = "The full name of A"
B.full_name = "The full name of B"

puts A.full_name # "The full name of A"
puts B.full_name # "The full name of B"
```

Comment: The “full_name” macro/accessor is only the simplest example; [some of them](https://github.com/slippyd/red_diamond/blob/master/lib/red_diamond/model/property_trait.rb) need to do a whole lot more. Further, the intent is creating a solidified model than can be depended on later in the code; allowing trivial re-definition defeats the purpose.

Comment: I've added clarification to the question that the given code is an example of what I'm attempting, not my exact code and that the given constraints are not flexible.